# Use password credential flow and some 3rd party authorization server

Tags: oauth-2.0

This is more of a general question but I hope it is still valid for SO.

So far I have learned, that in general, a mobile app (such as official Pinterest app) use the *Password credential flow* to let their users login and access the API directly. (let's just assume they use OAuth for this)

So they collect username and password, send it to their server and get a token in return which is used for subsequent requests.

Now a user did not want to register and created an account using e.g. Facebook as the authorization server. So my question is:

How is this flow implemented?

My educated guess:

1. User chooses "Login with Facebook" in mobile app
2. Facebook Login Page opens with return_uri = mobile app
3. Mobile app receives auth token
4. Mobile app uses *client credentials* and says the API: Use this token for user X

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, apps should not use the Password Credentials Grant. The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is rather clear about it:

> In the traditional client-server authentication model, the client
> requests an access-restricted resource (protected resource) on the
> server by authenticating with the server using the resource owner's
> credentials.  In order to provide third-party applications access to
> restricted resources, the resource owner shares its credentials with
> the third party. This creates several problems and limitations

The specification then goes on describing those problems.

And about the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant:

> The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not viable.

The entire purpose of OAuth 2.0, I to not have to use something like the Password Credentials Grant, where the user hands over their password to the application.

About your second question: what happens when a user does not want to register and create an account with your app, but wants to use e.g. Facebook for authentication?

Remember that both the Implicit Grant, as well as the Authorization Code Grant, work by using a browser control to authenticate the user. In that browser session with the Authorization Server, you are free to authenticate your user in any which way you want. Certainly, you can use your own user/password database, but you could also use other mechanisms, such as WS-Federation. In your case, it sounds like the user want to authenticate using Facebook.

Authenticating using Facebook is then not done by your client app, but by your Authorization Server. It typically does that by using the Facebook Authorization Code Grant, followed by a call to read the user's profile to obtain their Facebook user id, name, and so on.

If you do not want to build such an Authorization server yourself, you can use an existing one. Several companies offer login-as-a-service solutions, including [the one I work for](https://theidentityhub.com).

**UPDATE**: You asked several follow up questions in a comment below. I'll answer them briefly here:

First of all, the fact that some companies that use OAuth to secure their services allow for a Password Credentials Grant, does not imply that you should. In fact, there are probably more examples of companies that don't offer this possibility, than companies that do.

There are real trust issues, and real security risks with sharing your password with a device app. To start with, the app on the device is easier to hack than a server. Furthermore, if you give the app your password, presumably that app also needs to store it somewhere for future use. As a user, I just have to hope that that storage is safe form possible malware running on my machine. For more issues, see the introduction in the OAuth 2.0 specification mentioned above.

Secondly, all good Authorization Servers differentiate between First Party Clients and Third Party Clients. A First Party Client such as yours is controlled by the same company that controls the Authorization Server, and for such an app the Authorization Server does not ask for user permission to share data, since it makes no sense to talk about sharing data with yourself. That is why the web sites of these companies don't ask you whether you allow to share the data they hold on your behalf with them. They already have it, and there is no "sharing" going on.

Of course, you might argue that you have never seen any of these companies talking about this distinction between First Party Clients and Third Party Clients. But the reason they don't should be obvious: when you deal with them, you are always a Third Party App. They don't need to tell you that they treat themselves differently.

The mechanism I would choose in your scenario depends on the nature of the client app, and the nature of the services it accesses. What are your requirements?

Anyway, if the device the application is running on has a secure storage facility, such as Windows Phone 8.1, I would probably consider using the Authorization Code Grant without client credentials. That way, the user never has to log in again. If we're talking about a web site or a SPA, I would consider the Implicit Grant (where the "remember me" feature, if any, is offered by the Authorization Server). Again, the specification gives advantages and disadvantages of each grant type for several scenario's.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Can you explain what stategy you would use for in-app authorization (given that it is *our* app belonging to *our* service)? Wouldn't be a great UX if the user gets a browser window asking if "XYZ App" is allowed to access "XYZ Service". Foursquare, Facebook, Pinterest you name it offer both username/password auth AND third-party login flow.

Comment: Am I correct thinking that the oAuth2 login for ex facebooks doesn't bring any actual security, because an evil third party app could easily fake the login screen, snatch your password and then log you in using the open Password Credential Grant and the end user would never notice the difference? Only if you have (third party) Confidential clients that allows for higher access level (more scopes) than the Password Credential Grants can give, you may have an extended security since the confidential client also identifies itself?

Comment: @AndreasLundgren In a browser, you know that you are indeed talking to the real Facebook (for example) by looking at the address bar and the server certificate. If it's a device app that hides that information, you indeed have an issue. You basically have to trust the app. What you could also do is log in and authorize the app, and immediately go to Facebook and change your password. If the app stops working, they stole your password. You can also consult the apps page in Facebook, and see what scopes you have granted to what app.

Comment: @AndreasLundgren  That being said, OAuth is never worse than the alternative, which is giving your password to the app.